# How to make auto update android application without play store?

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

When I try this code it get me error when i try to path for install fille--> content then I get "there was a problem parsing the package" error on installation.

This code is in update click event in android studio.

```
 String destination = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/";
                                String fileName = "battlegame.apk";
                                destination += fileName;
                                final Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + destination);

                                //Delete update file if exists
                                File file = new File(destination);
                                if (file.exists()){

                                    file.delete();
                                 }


                                String url = downloadurl;


                                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                                request.setDescription("Updating....");
                                request.setTitle("Battle Game");


                                request.setDestinationUri(uri);


                                final DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                                final long downloadId = manager.enqueue(request);


                                final String finalDestination = destination;
                                BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                                    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {


                                        Log.d("Update status", "Download completed   "+uri.toString()+"      id   "+String.valueOf(downloadId));



                                        Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                        install.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(finalDestination)),
                                                "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                                        install.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                        startActivity(install);






                                        unregisterReceiver(this);

                                    }
                                };

                                registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
```

My download was perfectly work but install app not work.
below error i get. I pasted logcat for it..

```
D/Update status: Download completed   file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/battlegame.apk      id   135
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.di.battlegame, PID: 7344
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE flg=0x10 pkg=com.di.battlegame (has extras) } in com.di.battlegame.FirstActivity$1$2$1@c0b3ffb
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args(LoadedApk.java:1560)
        at android.app.-$$Lambda$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args$_BumDX2UKsnxLVrE6UJsJZkotuA.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/battlegame.apk exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
        at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:2083)
        at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2388)
        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:10791)
        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:10744)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1703)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5192)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5150)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5521)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5489)
        at com.di.battlegame.FirstActivity$1$2$1.onReceive(FirstActivity.java:191)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args(LoadedApk.java:1550)
        at android.app.-$$Lambda$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args$_BumDX2UKsnxLVrE6UJsJZkotuA.run(Unknown Source:2) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 7344 SIG: 9
Process 7344 terminated.
```

After solving this problem I get this error on android device when I install app.

I get **There was a problem parsing the package** error.

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58988946/when-i-install-app-for-update-current-app-then-i-get-error-there-was-a-problem?noredirect=1#comment104231935_58988946)

for see my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/test.txt exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed)

Comment: above method I try but not work for me

Comment: my problem is not install app after download i get parse error.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from N you can't expose Uri file:// to another apps, use [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider) instead.

Comment: when i try content for install this error gone but after problem is "There was problem parsing the package" in device.

Comment: Do you have any new exceptions?

Comment: When I use FileProvider then I get  this exeption....    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority com.****.***.provider

Comment: I solve above exception but apk not install and logcat not seen anything

Comment: I get "There was a problem parsing the package" error

Comment: If you got  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority com then it means you don't declare your provider correctly